# Importing .js file into html using <script>

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked at different posts on StackOverflow but I can't seem to solve this problem despite following the suggestions. Any help would be appreciated.

I have the following HTML code in the file home.html in my frontend folder:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <title> Home Page </title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src ="src/home.js"></script>
  </head> 
  </html>`
```

And I have a file home.js in the folder src that I'm trying to import. However, when I then run localhost I get the error:

The resource from “http://localhost:3000/src/home.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

I've tried adding

`app.use("/src", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../src")));
  app.use("/frontend", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend")));`

to my server.js file but it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check what response you're actually getting: it looks like your server is returning HTML not js

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359211/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359211/resource-blocked-due-to-mime-type)

Answer (score -2):

Add along with the "type" attribute as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-javascript-file.js"></script>
```

Comment: That tells the browser to *expect* a `text/javascript` response, the server's HTTP response headers are still authoritative.